# Undefined reference on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: c++, linux, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I have simple subscriber project, but there some problems. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 2.6.38-11-generic, gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4), GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.21.0.20110327 and GNU Make 3.81.
I have

1. /project/include/DepthListener.h,
2. /project/src/DepthListener.cpp,
3. /project/src/depthConverter.cpp.

When I try to make project, I receive next errors:

```
CMakeFiles/depthListener.dir/src/depthListener.o: In function `main':
/ros/depthListen/src/depthListener.cpp:6: undefined reference to `DepthConverter::DepthConverter()'
/ros/depthListen/src/depthListener.cpp:6: undefined reference to `DepthConverter::~DepthConverter()'
/ros/depthListen/src/depthListener.cpp:6: undefined reference to `DepthConverter::~DepthConverter()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I undestand, make does not see DepthListener.cpp file and problem somewhere in CMakeLists.txt.

There are all files:

1. [DepthConverter.h](http://pastebin.com/XbT6yHgC)
2. [CMakeLists.txt](http://pastebin.com/SNq2VrHC)
3. [DepthConverter.cpp](http://pastebin.com/CNS7nR6m)
4. [depthListener](http://pastebin.com/LsrFNnZn)

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11559/undefined-reference-on-ubuntu-11.04/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2011-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked briefly at your CMakeLists, I think this should fix it:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(depthListener src/depthListener.cpp 
                                      src/depthConverter.cpp)
```

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2011-10-15**:
Thanks, it works fine! So silly mistake.